# java.util.logging message template question

Tags: java, logging

NetBeans recommended that I change the way that logging statements that have string concatenation are written, stating **Convert string concatenation to a message template** so that a statement such as:

```
log.severe("Completed at:  " + new Date());
```

got changed to

```
log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Completed at:  {0}", new Date());
```

The problem is that now the Date doesn't get printed. Instead, the string "{0}" literatlly gets printed instead. Is there something else I was suppose to do?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the code snippet you posted is not the original code that was causing problems... Having a single apostrophe in your message will cause the type of a problem you described. `java.util.logging.Logger.log` passes the message to `java.text.MessageFormat` which [requires you to escape apostrophes](http://blogs.oracle.com/byuan/entry/best_practices_of_handling_apostrophes).

For example:

```
log.log( Level.FINE, "Can't handle {0}.", id );
log.log( Level.FINE, "Can''t handle {0}.", id );
```

Logs:

```
Cant handle {0}.
Can't handle ID0001.
```

Comment: That was the original code. So it wasn't an issue with apostrophies. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: Thanks! In my case that was the problem. I was being puzzled, because {0} and {1} were printed fine, but {2} didn't. It was, of course that I had an apostrophe somewhere between the {1} and {2}.

Answer (score 0):

I know that `PrintStream` has a [`format`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method that works that way, though Java uses the C-like [`%` prefix](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) instead of the C#-like `{}` wrapper. But `Logger` has no such method. You are instead invoking an override of [`log`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#log%28java.util.logging.Level,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) which in my experience only logs the string exactly as given, and does nothing with the `Object` parameter.